# Switch between hover/active on menu items in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to remove an "active"-class from the menu items when hovering another menu item?

There's a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SKmTh/). By default the home button has the "active"-class, whenever hovering over an other menu item i'd like to have that "active"-class removed. In this manner, only 1 menu item has the menu overlay ontop of it. Is this easy achievable by using CSS? Or do I need some fancy JavaScript?

The following piece of code will place the button overlay ontop of my menu items:

```
#menu li a.active,
#menu li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url('../images/menu_button_overlay.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 30px 10px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Or do I need some fancy JavaScript?" ...Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be possible with CSS.

```
#menu:hover .active {
     background: none;   
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKmTh/7/)

Comment: This is more or less what I mean, thanks! Altho whenever you're on the menu div, and not touching any menu item, it'll still remove the overlay. So it's not a 100% solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Fancy Javascript. But even then, I doubt, it won't work because After you remove the `active` class from home any other menu item will have the overlay only till you `hover` it or click on it. If you do not click on any other menu item then in the end there won't be any overlay for any menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You would need javascript (or more likely Jquery)

**JQuery**

```
$("li a").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $("li a").not(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/SKmTh/4/)

Comment: This is not entirely what i'd mentioned. I like to hover over menu items and then only see 1 overlay. When i leave the menu items, i want the old active-class to be restored.